# PHP if-else parsing error

Tags: php, parsing

I've finally started to learn PHP and I quite have trouble with it. I am trying to make a website change its stylesheet according to the moment of the day (day, twilight, night) and I've taken this approach:

```
<?php
    $lt = localtime();
    if ($lt[2]>=6 && $lt[2]<=16)
       echo('<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
    elsif ($lt[2]>=17 && $lt[2]<=21)
        echo('<link href="style_twilight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
    else
        echo('<link href="style_night.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
?>
```

I get *syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in ...../style_changer.php on line 12*

What am doing wrong?

Comment: It is [`elseif`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php), and you ought to be using curly braces.

Comment: it might be easier for your to read if you just type `echo "<b>something</b>";` without the `()`'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[elseif/else if <sup>manual</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Its `elseif` *(no space between else & if)* not `elsif`

```
elseif ($lt[2]>=17 && $lt[2]<=21)
```

Answer (score 0):

at first very simple typo elsif instead of els_e_if.

Answer (score 0):

To clean up your code:

```
<?php
$lt = localtime();

if ($lt[2]>=6 && $lt[2]<=16) {
   echo '<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
} elseif ($lt[2]>=17 && $lt[2]<=21) {
   echo '<link href="style_twilight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
} else {
   echo '<link href="style_night.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
}
?>
```

Makes it easier to read, also use `{}` for seperating logic, its all about reading your code later (your or someone else)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 $lt = localtime();
    if ($lt >= 6 && $lt <= 16){
        echo '<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
          }
    elseif ($lt >= 17 && $lt <= 21){
        echo '<link href="style_twilight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
          }
    else{
        echo '<link href="style_night.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
          }
```

Firstly: It's `elseif(){ Do something } //Note the Curly brackets`

Secondly: Your `echo ('something';)` is incorrect. Should be: echo 'something';

Third: No need for `$lt[2] $lt` works fine